# Export Bulk insert statement by toad

Tags: sql, oracle, bulkinsert, toad

when I export data as insert statement it generates (abc.sql) huge insert statement that I have to run individually. Its not possible to run 10000 insert statement one by one. So how to export Bulk insert statement of selected data  by toad which I can run by a single click or few modification.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments to others answers I believe you are doing a lot of unnecessary export/editing/importing.  Let the database do all that work for you!

This works on my test table without all that shucking and jiving.  For all rows where the year is 2015 it will insert (in effect copy) the same data but with the year increased by 1:

```
insert into x_test
(select col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d, l_date + 365 from x_test  -- 2016
where to_char(l_date, 'YYYY') = '2015');
```

Add even more years at the same time with unions:

```
insert into x_test
(select col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d, l_date + 365 from x_test  -- 2016
where to_char(l_date, 'YYYY') = '2015')
union
(select col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d, l_date + 730 from x_test  -- 2017
where to_char(l_date, 'YYYY') = '2015');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no bulk insert. You could insert records from one table into another such as "insert into table (column) select t.column from temp_table t;"

Comment: There **is** bulk insert. But your idea is good. If the tables are in the same database. If databases are connected it can be used a db_link for this. Otherwise it can't be done without exporting data and reimporting it.

Comment: I got my desired answer. 10000 insert statement and just add BEGIN on top and END; / at last. Thanks to all.